# Codeigniter URI segment return boolean

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am new to Codeigniter and I am trying use `pagination`. My problem is unexpected, as my pagination code works perfectly except the URI segment always return as a boolean. My code is:

```
/* pagination */
$this->load->library('pagination');
$destination = $data['destination'];

$config = array();
$config["base_url"] = SEARCHHOTELS.$this->uri->segment(3);

$total_row = $this->db->get('hotel')->num_rows();
$config["total_rows"] = $total_row;
$config["per_page"] = 30;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config['num_links'] = $total_row;
$config['cur_tag_open'] = '<a class="active">';
$config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a>';
$config['next_link'] = 'Next';
$config['prev_link'] = 'Previous';
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$str_links = $this->pagination->create_links();


$this->db->select('*');
if(!empty($data['destination'])){
  $destination = $data['destination'];
  $this->db->like('name',$destination);
  $this->db->or_like('regionName',$destination);
}
$hSearch['records'] = $this->db->get('hotel',$config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(3))->result_array();
$hSearch["links"] = explode('&nbsp;',$str_links);
/* paginationEnd */
```

where SEARCHHOTELS constant is

```
define('SEARCHHOTELS', SITE_URL.'search/hotels/');
```

In my code: `$this->uri->segment(3)` always returns boolean.

When I click on my pagination, the URL value changes from:

```
http://localhost/holidays/search/hotels/
```

to:

```
http://localhost/holidays/search/hotels/1 (or 2,3,4)
```

The URI segment does not set offset the value in my `$this->db-get` query. #

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case anyone fall into this kind of trouble i want to share my solution which i found in two days.

The flow of my page was:

```
search-controller->search-view->alot-of-ajax-request->find-all-hotels();
```

The uri segment for pagination only work in controller i.e it will fetch segments before loading the view .

if you want to get the uri segment in a function that is called through the ajax.

It will not work and fetch only 2 segments that is controller and method after that all methods will be skipped .

hope this will help some one else

Comment: If you'd like to use Ajax request you need to call for your data and your pagination for corresponding data :). For ex.: if you are calling for data LIMIT 10, 30 you shouold also call for corresponding pagination html. / @Tpojka: his base_url i think was correct ;)

Comment: @PawelN His or mine?

Comment: @PawelN Code belongs to himself. :D According to [docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html#example) base url is string that doesn't include pagination changing part.

Answer (score 1):

From docs:

> $query = $this->db->get('mytable', 10, 20);
>
> // Executes: SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 20, 10
>
> // (in MySQL. Other databases have slightly different syntax)

That said, third parameter of `get()` method is limit but you are putting page number there. Switch places of second and third arguments. But you need to do some math there

```
$offset = (int)$this->uri->segment(3) > 0 ? ($this->uri->segment(3) - 1) * $config['per_page'] : 0;

$hSearch['records'] = $this->db->get('hotel', $offset, $config['per_page'])->result_array();
```

I think your base url of pagination should be

```
$config['base_url'] = SEARCHHOTELS;
```

without any segment after.

Comment: thanks for your answer dear but the problem here is that $this->uri->segment(3) should return url last segment which should be 1 2 3 or some int value to work with but its returning boolean . my query works perfectly when i put static values for pagination i-e 1 2 3 & 4

Comment: At very first line of the method put `var_dump($this->uri->segment_array());exit;` to debug it.

Comment: i also tried that it return 2 segments and further debugging first was search and 2nd  was hotels and hotel is at third segment further value of 1 2 etc does'nt pop up in segments .. bro i debug each line but with no luck my code isn't faulty

Comment: Have you passed argument to the method like `public function hotels($id = FALSE){/*code here*/}`?

Comment: yes and i also try to put it in url like .'?value='.$this->uri->segment(3); but nothing worked ..

Comment: That way wouldn't work. `?val1=5&val2=3` should be got with `$this->input->get('val1')` and `$this->input->get('val2')`. Can you test it with newly created Test controller? Uri segments should work by default.

Answer (score 0):

You should use $this->uri->segment(4) as your part of uri which hold page.
You should set config for pagination correctly:

```
$config['uri_segment'] = 4;
```

$this->uri->segment(3) is 'hotels' i your code. Am I right?

Comment: yes i tried that too but with no luck last value that pagination add ie 1 2 3 or 4 cant be picked with uri_segment ..